# OrientDB SQL create edge query error

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to create an edge between two vertices using a Python script (pyorient), but I'm getting a weird error message. I'm following the OrientDB SQL syntax and the query is the following:

```
client.command("Create ExtModToTimePoint from (select from ExtendedModel where name = 'EM') to (select from TimePoint where date = %s)" % today)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Error com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException - Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.Create
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

the correct command is `CREATE EDGE`, you're probably missing the EDGE word